# Did I just change const value in C++ using refrence?

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a = 137;
  const int &b = a;
  std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;  // prints 137 137
  a++;
  std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;  // prints 138 138
}
```

The value of variable `b` becomes `138` after `a++` statement, although it's declared as `const` Shouldn't this be not allowed? how to make sure this won't happen? or at least get a warning for doing that.

I am using `GNU GCC Compiler`

Comment: Nah, you changed the `int` variable, which the `const int` reference refers to

Comment: `const int &b=a` means it's a constant reference to `a` variable and not to the value `137`. Clearly, `a++` doesn't change this reference so you're abiding the `const` identifier rule.

Comment: More precise name for `const T&` would be `readonly T&`.

Comment: To put the period on the comments you've gotten: `b++` would not be allowed.

Comment: @subhamX This statement doesn't make sense. All C++ references are not rebindable, so they are "constant" by definition. In `const int&`, `const` applies not to the reference, but to an object the reference refers to.

Comment: @Evg, I think you got me wrong. You are correct that `All C++ references are not rebindable`. But `int &b=a` allows us to update the value of `a` by doing `b=400`. But in the case of `const int&b=a` we cannot do it. So my statement that `const int &b=a` is nothing but `b is a constant reference to a's value` is correct. Feel free to correct me. 

Comment: @subhamX I was confused by the statement "`a++` doesn't change this reference so you're abiding the `const` identifier rule": if you're talking about the reference itself, it can't be changed (rebinded) by definition, if you're talking about changing the object it points to, `a++` does change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't this be not allowed?

It's fine. Your code only prevents the `b` reference from changing the value, but the original variable `a` doesn't have such a restriction, so it can be freely changed.